# TFS Run batch script on a remote server with admin permission

Tags: batch-file, tfs, build-definition

I currently have Server A which is where my TFS and Build Agent is located. I then have Server B which is when my source code site. I am trying to set up a build definition and copies file from on location in server B to another and then build the solution.

However when I run this batch file as part of a build definition it is not creating folders where it need to be. I believe due to the agent not having correct permissions.

Is there a way to run the following batch script to run with Admin permission from a build definition.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try below workarounds:

1. Convert the batch script to PowerShell script, then copy the
   PowerShell script to target machine and use the [PowerShell on Target
   Machines](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/powershell-on-target-machines?view=vsts) task to run the script. You can enter your admin user
   and password using the task. Reference below screenshot.
2. Add a PowerShell task and run below script to call the `cmd.exe` to
   run the batch script with an admin user account on target machine
   (Copy the batch script to target machine first, in below sample I
   copied the batch script to `C:\Scripts\Test.bat`):

   ```
   Param(
     [string]$computerName = "v-tinmo-12r2",
   )
   $Username = "Domain\user"
   $Password = ConvertTo-SecureString "password-here" -AsPlainText -Force

   $cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($Username,$password)

   Invoke-Command -ComputerName $computerName  -Credential $cred -ErrorAction Stop -ScriptBlock {Invoke-Expression -Command:"cmd.exe /c 'C:\Scripts\Test.bat'"}
   ```

[image]